# Create a new instance of a control dynamically

Tags: c#, controls, instance

Ok so I have a form I'm building that's going to change it's interface by using custom controls.  What I'm trying to do is make several checks before a new control is created, like checking if one is already up.  I have everything working just fine but I can't seem to create the new control dynamically, without creating it before running the checks which defeats the purpose.

The controls all implement an interface called ICustomControl and inherit from a MasterControl. Then I have a custom control called JobForm, and a button on the main form that calls the method like so: `Check_Controls(newJobForm)`

```
JobForm newJobForm;

private void Check_Controls(Control control) // Checks current controls to see if a new one can be opened 
{
    bool currentControl = false;

    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        if (c is ICustomControl && c != masterControl)
            currentControl = true;
    }

    if (currentControl)
    {
        TimedMessageBox timedMessage = new TimedMessageBox("There is currently an open form.  Please close the current control before opening another.");
        timedMessage.ShowDialog();
    }
    else
    {
        Control c = (Control)Activator.CreateInstance(control.GetType());
        this.Controls.Add(c);
        Position_Control(c);
        c.Show();
    }
}
```

I dont't want to create a new instance of the custom control like: `JobForm newJobForm = new JobForm();` before running the check method, I want to pass the reference to the check method and then have it create the new instance after it's checks are complete.  In this way no matter how many new custom controls I wind up adding to the application, all I have to do to set one up is create the reference variable, then for the button call the check method and pass it the reference.

Anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are thinking about the problem backwards.  Instead of saying "I have control X, is it valid?" think "would control X be valid, if so create".  You are wanting to make checks to see if a control is valid, yet you want to send in a reference to that control.

Your code doesn't check for specific types of control, but rather just that at least one control belonging to the current form implements your interface.  If this is the intended behavior, just have a function that does your initial check to see if any ICustomControl exist on your form.  If that function return false, then go along with your creation.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, that's what I'm already doing...  maybe your not understanding what I'm trying to accomplish.  I have many buttons and each button opens a different control, but I don't want any overlapping controls, I only want one control to be open at a time...  Thus I'm checking if any controls are currently open, and if they are tells the user no and if they aren't opens the control.  A lot of the code is the same so I'm trying to condense it into a simple method that opens whatever control is passed to it.

Comment: Right, I'm saying you should separate the check from the creation.  Somewhere you are already creating these instances to pass into your existing function.  What I'm suggesting is to have your function ONLY do the check, but not the creation and have it return a bool if the control creation is valid.  If it's valid, the use your existing creation logic where ever that might be.

Comment: Ah, yah I thought about doing that, I was just hoping there was a way to condense that magic into a single generic method, instead of having to write it out for each creation.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a single function by using a constrained generic. This also gets you away from the less-than-ideal practice of using `Activator` and other reflection methods for dynamic type generation:

```
private void CheckAndAddControl<ControlType>()
    where ControlType : MasterControl, new()
{
    bool currentControl = false;

    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        if (c is ControlType)
        {
            currentControl = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (currentControl)
    {
        TimedMessageBox timedMessage = new TimedMessageBox("There is currently an open form.  Please close the current control before opening another.");
        timedMessage.ShowDialog();
    }
    else
    {
        var c = new ControlType();
        this.Controls.Add(c);
        Position_Control(c);
        c.Show();
    }
}
```

You would then use this function as follows:

```
CheckAndAddControl<JobForm>();
```